# finding height and width for different devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been working on an app which requires finding the height and width of different devices. If I remove the code for height and width the app works if i include the code the app crashes.

Can you please suggest what's wrong with the code.

Here's the code:

```
public class Newone extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newone);
    }

    final Context context = this;
    public String cntry = "";
    int w= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int w = metrics.widthPixels;
    int h = metrics.heightPixels;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        MotionEvent object holds X-Y values
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {              
            String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
            //Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if((event.getX()>((w/1280)*850)) && (event.getX()<((h/752)*900)) && (event.getY()>((w/1280)*380)) && (event.getY()<((h/752)*450)))
                if((event.getX()>850) && (event.getX()<900) && (event.getY()>380) && (event.getY()<450)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    display(cntry);
                }

                if((event.getX()>280) && (event.getX()<400) && (event.getY()>200) && (event.getY()<300)) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    cntry = "US";
                    display(cntry);
                }

                if((event.getX()>900) && (event.getX()<1200) && (event.getY()>500) && (event.getY()<650))
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }   

    private void display(final String cntry) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_newone, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: use the code for calculating width & hieght inside the onCreate method;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you move `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()`; and `getHeight()` and `metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();` inside you `onCreate` ? I'm not sure `context` and others are available at the `Activity`'s construction time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move following stuff inside onCreate.

```
final Context context = this;
public String cntry = "";


DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w = metrics.widthPixels;
int h = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Also `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();` and `getHeight` are now deprecated..So avoid using them.

Here is corrected snippet.

```
public class Newone extends Activity {
    final Context context;
    public String cntry = "";
    int w, h;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newone);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        context = this;

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        w = metrics.widthPixels;
        h = metrics.heightPixels;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = "
                    + event.getY();
            // Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if ((event.getX() > ((w / 1280) * 850))
                    && (event.getX() < ((h / 752) * 900))
                    && (event.getY() > ((w / 1280) * 380))
                    && (event.getY() < ((h / 752) * 450)))
                if ((event.getX() > 850) && (event.getX() < 900)
                        && (event.getY() > 380) && (event.getY() < 450))

                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    display(cntry);
                }

            if ((event.getX() > 280) && (event.getX() < 400)
                    && (event.getY() > 200) && (event.getY() < 300))

            { // Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cntry = "US";
                display(cntry);
            }

            if ((event.getX() > 900) && (event.getX() < 1200)
                    && (event.getY() > 500) && (event.getY() < 650)) {

            }

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void display(final String cntry) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_newone, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 except for...Why would you use `final Context context;` and `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();`? An `Activity` is a `Context`. There is no need to hold a `final Context` for something which will be referencing itself. An `Activity` can call `getResources()` at any time without needing a `context` or `this` prefix.

Comment: above code works when targeting for a single android device but when trying for making app work for mobile and tablet,code is crashing.

Comment: @Squonk I declared context in hope that OP may need to pass it as argument to other class in future.For this code there is certainly no need to create context variable.

Comment: @VipulShah: The code is working for a single android device, but i have multiple xml pointing to different devices and it is when the code is crashing. Can u suggest something?

Comment: please someone reply .. i have a deadline :(